# Install XCode 5.1.1 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: xcode, macos

I have `Xcode 4.6` installed on my mac with `OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5)`

Now I want to install `Xcode 5.1.1` and keep `Xcode 4.6` installed.

Is this a good idea or would the old `Xcode 4` interfere with the new version 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode apps are now *self-contained*, meaning that the SDK and tools they carry are all hidden within their application package.

So you can install Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 side by side, as long as you make it clear to yourself which version is which (on my own machine, I keep my Xcode 4 in a "`Xcode4`" folder).

The only possible conflict I can imagine is that if you're using command line tools (to build open source stuff or use makefiles or whatever), you'll likely want to specify which compilers and tools get used, which you can do via the "`xcode-select`" tool.  Using this requires "`sudo`" and admin access:

```
xcode-select: error: no command option given
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example, 
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
```